# Angular animation within *ngfor executed only once

Tags: angular, single-page-application

I have a bsic animation that relies within an element that generated within *ngFor.

It works while the first animation executed (basically after a blur event from a text box)

The animation is  very basic.
No errors on the console

Animation within the Component:

```
animations: [
    trigger('a1', [
      state('in', style({
        opacity: 1,
        transform: 'translateX(0)'
      })),
      transition('*=> *', [
        style({
          opacity: 0.1,
          transform: 'translateX(100px)'
        }),
        animate(2000)
      ])
    ])
  ]
```

Template:

```
<div
  class="answer"
  id="answer{{i}}"
  [@a1]>
</div>
```

The tenplate resides within a simple *ngFor that looks like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let exec of exercices; index as i">
```

basically the directive that palced on othe element within the *ngFor is addign a new CSS classes that results with Icons added to this Div

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

A angular animation begins:

1. When you use `[@animation]`: if you use `:enter` or `:leave`
   [aliases](https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers#enter-and-leave-aliases)
2. When you use `[@animation]="variable"`: if the variable change

I'm not pretty sure what are you trying to do :(

Comment: Since the icon that I am trying to animate can added at anytime through a directive I used a wild card to achieve that, it does work but only for the first animation, there is a page full with exercices and an icon is added depends on the answer when blur event occurs via a directive which also add the CSS accordingly, I've tried to use :enter and :leave but once again it happens only once, I understand that it best practices to work with void and * instead of state variable in case that we dont know when the application beggins